# Angular: How to access an element directive's scope in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this simple Angular module:

```
angular.module('fixturesModule', [])
.directive('clubfixtures', function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            club : "@club",
            max : "@max"
        },

    templateUrl: "ClubResultsTemplate.html",

    controller: function ($scope, $http) {

        $http.get("data.json").success(function (data) {
            $scope.results = data;
        });

        $scope.sortBy = "Date";

    }
}
});
```

How do I access club and max in the controller function?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: In which controller function? In the controller function for the directive? Or in the controller function for the parent of the directive?

Comment: In the `function($scope, $http)` assigned to `controller` shown in the example above. Specifically the `club` value will form part of the path in the `$http.get`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 mentioned variables (`max` and `club`) will be simply defined in a scope injected to directive's controller. This means that you can write:

```
controller: function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.max; //do sth with $scope.max
        $scope.club //so sth with $scope.club

        $http.get("data.json").success(function (data) {
            $scope.results = data;
        });
}
```

in your directive's controller.

If you want to read up more I would suggest the "Directive Definition Object" in the http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive where it talks about scopes in directives.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. However when I add `console.log($scope.club);` to the controller function, I just get undefined as the output.

Comment: I would need to see more code to help more, specifically how the directive is used in HTML and what data are available in the scope where it is used. Do you think it would be possible for you to provide a jsFiddle / plunk with the live code?

Comment: Been reading through [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and it seems you can access $attrs. Adding `$attrs` to `function ($scope, $http, $attrs)` and `console.log($attrs.club);` worked.

Comment: @pkoz I'm having the same problem myself, `$scope.max` is undefined. So do you have to use `$attrs` and not `$scope` inside the controller of the directive? Is that the only way to access the attributes?

Answer (score 10):

Attributes on the scope set up with '@', as in `scope: { myAttr: '@' }` receive their values *after* the controller function has been called.

You can demonstrate this with a simple setTimeout - See http://jsfiddle.net/Q4seC/ (be sure to open the console)

$attrs, as you've found, is ready when you need it.

Interestingly, if you use '=' instead of '@', the value is ready and available, which makes me think this could be considered a bug in Angular...

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: +1 for this being the most useful answer, although it still doesn't confirm why these scope properties are undefined at the point of the controller function. Confirmed as a bug? Any more information?

Comment: This seems pretty undesirable, and I haven't found a technical reason for it. I came across this looking for a way to default `@`-passed string values. The most official way I've seen to deal with this is to use [`attrs.$observe()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe). Doing something like `attrs.$observer('prop', function(val) { scope.prop = val || 'default'; });` will update `{{prop}}` bindings and probably give you the desired outcome, albeit not immediately at `postLink`.